# Testing of PHP Fails

Tags: server, permissions, apache2, php, lamp

I am trying to add a LAMP Web Server by following the instructions at "http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/42480/how-to-turn-your-home-ubuntu-pc-into-a-lamp-web-server/"

I ran the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install lamp-server^
```

Everything seemed to install okay.

Testing of Apache worked fine using the localhost check

Next, I tried to test PHP by creating the file

```
sudo nano /var/www/testing.php
  <?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

I checked to make sure the file is located in the following directory:

```
Root/var/www/testing.php
```

I then restarted Apache with the following command:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Next I tried to load the following page in my web browser:

http://localhost/testing.php

I receive the following error message:

> Not Found -    The requested URL /testing.php was not found on this server. -    Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80

I checked to make sure PHP installed correctly using the following command:

```
~$ php --version
```

Which returned:

```
PHP 7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 (cli) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2016 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.0.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2016 Zend Technologies
  with Zend OPcache v7.0.13-0ubuntu0.16.04.1, Copyright (c) 1999-2016, by    Zend Technologies
```

Any ideas why I can not access testing php file, and why I am getting the 404 not found error message?

Comment: Which is the directory  `DocumentRoot` set in your `000-default.conf`?

Comment: Move the file from `/var/www/testing.php` to `/var/www/html/testing.php` and try again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `DocumentRoot` to `/var/www`  in the following configuration files solved the problem.

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

Comment: If @user3333911 answer solved your problem it's customary to accept it rather than repeat it. We have no shortage of [unanswered questions](http://askubuntu.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=noanswers) here and your help would be appreciated. Reviewing http://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-answer first is highly recommended.  While writing a better answer based on an existing one is permissible, [straight duplication](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/14529/should-almost-identical-answers-be-deleted/16793#16793) is frowned on.

Answer (score 2):

Check `DocumentRoot` in

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

and

```
/etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf
```

Comment: Both documents are found in the root/etc/apache2/sites-available/ directory?

Comment: Look what you have in /etc/apache2

Comment: I have in /etc/apache2  apache2.conf   envvars   magic   ports.conf